# Cannot find function renderEcharts4r in Shiny Quarto document

Tags: r, shiny, echarts, quarto, echarts4r

Round 2. I am creating a quarto/shiny doc that has an echart graphic in it with a simple radio button input widget,and the error that I am running into now is a 'Error in renderEcharts4r({ : could not find function "renderEcharts4r" '. The function does exist in the package though when I am looking through the functions in the packages pane!

Below is a reproducible example. What is the issue here? I've also tried downloading the package using devtools but I get the same error.

Thanks

**EDIT to include versions:**

echarts4r 0.4.5 (downloaded from CRAN) 
R version 4.3.2

````
---
title: "Test"
format: html
server: shiny
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
---


```{r}

#| label: setup

library(dplyr)
library(echarts4r)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(lubridate)


data("USAccDeaths")
USAccDeaths <- data.frame(as.matrix(USAccDeaths), date=time(USAccDeaths))
USAccDeaths$year <- trunc(USAccDeaths$date)
USAccDeaths$month <- (USAccDeaths$date - USAccDeaths$year) * 12 + 1
colnames(USAccDeaths)[1] <- 'Deaths'

```

```{r}

radioGroupButtons(
  inputId = "time_period",
  label = "Choices", 
  choices = c("Month", "Year"),
  status = "primary"
)

echarts4rOutput("plot1")

```

```{r}
#| context: server

deaths <- reactive({
  USAccDeaths %>% 
    group_by(tolower(input$time_period)) %>% 
    summarise('Deaths' = sum(deaths))
})


output$plot1 <- renderEcharts4r({
  deaths |> 
    e_charts(x = tolower(input$time_period)) |> # initialise and set x
    e_line(serie = Deaths, smooth = TRUE) |>
    e_tooltip(trigger = "axis")
  
})

```
````

Comment: Need version number for everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is the same as with your former question: Remove the empty line between the backticks and `#| label: setup`. Besides of this there are several other issues in your code. First, it should be `sum(Deaths)` instead of `sum(deaths)`. Second, as `deaths` is a `reactive` you have to add `()` to access its value in `renderEcharts4r`. Third, `input$time_period` is a character string and will not work in `group_by`. Instead you have to wrap in the `.data` pronoun or use `across` or ... . Finally, to simplify a bit I pass a named vector to the `choices=` argument to get rid of `tolower()` and in the `group_by` I create a new column `time_period` which could then be used when creating the chart.

````
---
title: "Test"
format: html
server: shiny
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
---


```{r}
#| label: setup
library(dplyr)
library(echarts4r)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(lubridate)

data("USAccDeaths")
USAccDeaths <- data.frame(as.matrix(USAccDeaths), date = time(USAccDeaths))
USAccDeaths$year <- trunc(USAccDeaths$date)
USAccDeaths$month <- (USAccDeaths$date - USAccDeaths$year) * 12 + 1
colnames(USAccDeaths)[1] <- "Deaths"
```

```{r}
radioGroupButtons(
  inputId = "time_period",
  label = "Choices",
  choices = c(Month = "month", Year = "year"),
  status = "primary"
)

echarts4rOutput("plot1")
```

```{r}
#| context: server

deaths <- reactive({
  USAccDeaths %>%
    group_by(time_period = .data[[input$time_period]]) %>%
    summarise(Deaths = sum(Deaths))
})


output$plot1 <- renderEcharts4r({
  deaths() |>
    e_charts(
      x = time_period
    ) |>
    e_line(serie = Deaths, smooth = TRUE) |>
    e_tooltip(trigger = "axis")
})
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thx @TarJae. Just fixed it. BTW: Happy new year! (:

Comment: do you think that there is a disadvantage if we omit/move `deaths <- reactive({
  USAccDeaths %>%
    group_by(time_period = .data[[input$time_period]]) %>%
    summarise(Deaths = sum(Deaths))
})` and just do like this :`#| context: server

output$plot1 <- renderEcharts4r({
  USAccDeaths %>%
    group_by(time_period = .data[[input$time_period]]) %>%
    summarise(Deaths = sum(Deaths)) |>
    e_charts(
      x = time_period
    ) |>
    e_line(serie = Deaths, smooth = TRUE) |>
    e_tooltip(trigger = "axis")
})`

Comment: @TarJae For the present use case I don't see any disadvantage. However, in terms of good coding practice, I would personally keep codes devoted to data wrangling and creation of charts separate.